# wget newest file in another server's folder

Tags: linux, wget

I have an automatic backup of a file running on a cronjob. It outputs into a folder, let's call `/backup`, and appends a timestamp to each file, every hour, like so:

`file_08_07_2013_01_00_00.txt`, `file_08_07_2013_02_00_00.txt`, etc.

I want to download these to another server, to keep as a separate backup. I normally just use `wget` and download a specific file, but was wondering how I could automate this, ideally every hour it would download the most recent file.

What would I need to look into to set this up?

Thanks!

Comment: How about `rsync`? It's a lot more flexible than `wget`. There's some examples [here](http://rsync.samba.org/examples.html) and [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/rsync-command-examples/)

Answer (score 1):

`wget` can handle that, just enable time-stamping. I'm not even going to attempt my own explanation, here's a [**direct quote from the manual**:](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Time_002dStamping)

> The usage of time-stamping is simple. Say you would like to download a
>   file so that it keeps its date of modification.
>
> ```
> wget -S http://www.gnu.ai.mit.edu/
> ```
>
> A simple ls -l shows that the time stamp on the local file equals the state of the Last-Modified
>   header, as returned by the server. As you can see, the time-stamping
>   info is preserved locally, even without ‘-N’ (at least for http).
>
> Several days later, you would like Wget to check if the remote file
>   has changed, and download it if it has.
>
> ```
> wget -N http://www.gnu.ai.mit.edu/
> ```
>
> Wget will ask the server for the last-modified date. If the local file has the same timestamp as
>   the server, or a newer one, the remote file will not be re-fetched.
>   However, if the remote file is more recent, Wget will proceed to fetch
>   it.

Comment: isn't -N for the same file name?